# Flutter: Future function is calling continuously

Tags: flutter, future, provider

I use the future function to retrieve data from an API and I use consumer to wrap it because  then only when there is a change in data my list get updated. My code works fine but my future function is calling continuously.
My code is a given below

```
                    Consumer<Category>(
                      builder: (context, category, child) {
                        return FutureBuilder(
                            future: category.getAllCategories(), //returns a list
                            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                              if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data.isEmpty) {
                                return Center(
                                  child: Container(
                                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                  ),
                                );
                              } else {
                                return ListView.builder(
                                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                    itemCount:
                                        category.getlength != 0 || category.getlength != null || !category.getAllCatisempty ? category.getlength : 0,
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                      return InkWell(
                                        onTap: () async {
                                          try {

                                            print('connection Status ${await DataConnectionChecker().connectionStatus}');
                                            setState(() {

                                              _selectedIndex = index;
                                              timeCount = 0;

                                            });

                                            productsProvider.clearProductList();
                                            productsProvider.getAllProductsInCategory(category.allCategoryList[index].catId);

                                            setState(() {
                                              catId = category.allCategoryList[index].catId;
                                            });
                                          } catch (e) {
                                            print('exception category click $e');
                                          }
                                        },
                                        child: Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            Card(
                                              color: _selectedIndex != null && _selectedIndex == index ? selectedColor : defColor,
                                              elevation: _selectedIndex != null && _selectedIndex == index ? 4.0 : 1.0,
                                              child: Center(
                                                child: Padding(
                                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                                                  child: Container(
                                                    child: Padding(
                                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                                      child: Column(
                                                        children: <Widget>[
                                                          Image.network(
                                                            category.allCategoryList[index].catThumbnail,
                                                            width: 80.0,
                                                            height: 50.0,
                                                            scale: 1.0,
                                                            loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child, ImageChunkEvent loadingProgress) {
                                                              if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
                                                              return Center(
                                                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                                                  value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null
                                                                      ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded / loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes
                                                                      : null,
                                                                ),
                                                              );
                                                            },
                                                          ),
                                                          Padding(
                                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0),
                                                            child: Text(
                                                              category.allCategoryList[index].catName,
                                                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 10.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                                            ),
                                                          )
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    });
                              }
                            });
                      },
                    )
```

This is my log

```
I/flutter (25780): getAllCategories 
I/flutter (25780): getAllCategories 
I/flutter (25780): getAllCategories 
I/flutter (25780): getAllCategories 
I/flutter (25780): getAllCategories 
I/flutter (25780): getAllCategories 
I/flutter (25780): getAllCategories 
I/flutter (25780): getAllCategories 
I/flutter (25780): getAllCategories 
I/flutter (25780): getAllCategories 
I/flutter (25780): getAllCategories
```

This goes on continuously.

Can any one help me with this

Answer (score 3):

Looking at provided example it looks like you're getting the Future during Flutter's `build` phase.

FutureBuilder's [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) explicitly states that this would cause repetitive invocations of provided Future:

> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during State.initState, State.didUpdateConfig, or State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the FutureBuilder. If the future is created at the same time as the FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt, the asynchronous task will be restarted.

Basically, every time your widget gets rebuilt by Flutter rendering pipeline you initialize new `getAllCategories()` call.

Recommended way to avoid this effect is to initialize your Future in `State.initState`, `State.didUpdateConfig`, or `State.didChangeDependencies`.

Comment: I already tried that it will solved this recursive calling issue but that load the list when there app goes from offline to online.

Comment: Yes, online/offline state changes will need to be handled separately. This can be addressed in several different ways. A couple very common ones:

(1) If call to getAllCategories() fails with network error, remember this error in your State and show "You are offline" message with possibly "Try again" button. 
(2) More complex solution is to keep track of online/offline state of your app and expose it as a `Stream<bool>`. So in your State object you can subscribe to this stream and react to offline/online notifications on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

try to initialize future in initState

```
Future _getCategories;

 initState(){
  super.initState();
  _getCategories= category.getAllCategories();
}
build(){
 return FutureBuilder(
   future:_getCategories,
   builder:(context,snapshot){
    return ...
   }
 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It saves time.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell precisely what is causing this without testing myself, but is it possible that you have a setState inside FutureBuilder which is rebuilding your widget and because of that, it keeps calling again and again?

Comment: I mean, you're using Providers as your state management right? Your code looks a little confusing because I don't think you have a full understanding of the concept. These might help you: 
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple 
Example with Future:
https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-statemanagement-with-provider-ee251bbc5ac1

I believe you should get rid of this FutureBuilder and make the ListView build itself by listening to the Category changes. Also, pylyaevskiy`s answer is correct too. You shouldn't be calling the Future inside build()

Comment: As you said I don't have much understanding of the concept. What I need is a  List view that autoload when there is internet connection.